# Python retrieved data from database which is encoded by Latin1_swedish_ci in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, utf-8, latin1

I have a database storing text with Latin1_swedish_ci.
If I retrieved the data from this database by php (encoding in utf-8), I got the correct result

Here is the result:

> measured at Dungsha coraisland (20°42’N, 116°43’E) during the South China Sea Monsoon Experiment (May-June 1998) have been calibrated and compared with radiative transfer calculations for three clear-sky days.

However, when I use python with mysql connector, I got the wrong result!

Here is the result:

> Downward total solar fluxes measured at Dungsha coraisland (20¢X42¡¦N, 116¢X43¡¦E) during the South China Sea Monsoon Experiment (May-June 1998) have been calibrated and compared with radiative transfer calculations for three clear-sky days.

Currently,part of my codes look like this:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host ='localhost',user='root', database='tao',charset='utf8',use_unicode='true')
f = io.open("upload.xml",'w',encoding='utf-8')
f.write(row[dic['abs']]+"\n")
```

Can someone help me? I need to retrieve all the data from the database by Python and output them into the xml file

Moreover, I am wondering why I can successfully get the correct result (20°42’N, 116°43’E) by php's echo? I have already check the data by using mysql> select..., and the result is also like this 20¢X42¡¦N, 116¢X43¡¦E.

Comment: Ok, back up a second. remove `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")`. Change your database back to how it was, set your mysql connector to: `connect(host ='localhost',user='root', database='tao', charset = 'utf-8',  use_unicode=True)`. With the text from the DB result do: `io.open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(result_message)`. Now paste what you have.

Comment: It did not work... I follow your methods. Since system told me I can only put unicode in write(), and hence I convert all my strings to unicode by unicode(). However, I checked my xml file and I still got this, 20¢X42¡¦N, 116¢X43¡¦E, which was not I wanted...

Comment: The results from the DB should already be Unicode. What encoding did you pass to `unicode()`?

Comment: Since I have to use this program to output a xml file, I do like this: f.write(unicode("\t<record>\n"))

Comment: Besides, the problem will occur when program did f.write(unicode(row[dic['abs']]+"\n")). row[dic['abs'] is the text encoding in Latin1_swedish_ci in MySQL.

Comment: Ok. Just write the result from the DB without any formatting or `unicodes()`.

Comment: but I can not write the result from the DB without unicodes(), otherwise it will say "TypeError: must be unicode, not str"

Comment: I'm presuming Python 2.7. Something is very screwy - The MySQL driver should be returning Unicodes by default (or if you set `use_unicode=True`, like I stated above). Then, you can't create Unicodes from non-ASCII strings using `unicode()` without an encoding defined, unless you've been fiddling with `sys.setdefaultencoding("utf8")`. That should be throwing an exception. Can you validate with `print type(row[dic['abs'])`. Also, please provide more of your code for a [mcve]

Comment: I am so sorry, I made a mistake. I can remove unicode() and it works. However, the result is still like 20¢X42¡¦N, 116¢X43¡¦E. I am wondering why php can show the correct result: 20°42’N, 116°43’E when I echo? As I know, php's default encoding is "utf8". Moreover, i also check the data in mysql database. When I select (mysql > select), the result also show 20¢X42¡¦N, 116¢X43¡¦E. Any idea what are the differences between them?

Comment: now my code looks like this: cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host ='localhost',user='root', database='tao',charset='utf8',use_unicode='true'),  f = io.open("upload.xml",'w',encoding='utf-8'), f.write(row[dic['abs']]+"\n")

Comment: PHP's default encoding is not UTF-8 (it's mostly iso-8859-1). PHP will pass byte strings without modification, as long as you don't do any manipulation. I suspect what's happening in your PHP, is you're passing the data straight back to your browser and your browser is autodetecting Big5, (as deduced by  @RickJames). Can you verify?

Answer (score 1):

Yikes!  I think you went through both latin1 and big5 character sets.
`3230A2583432A1A64E` is hex for `20¢X42¡¦N` in `CHARACETER SET latin1`
`3230A2583432A1A64E` is hex for `20°42’N` in `CHARACETER SET big5`
`3230C2B03432E280994E` is hex for `20°42’N` in `CHARACETER SET utf8`, which (I guess) is what you wanted stored.

It is enough of a nightmare to deal with both latin1 and utf8.  But throwing big5 into the mix makes my head spin.

The *connection* to mysql is willing to convert from whatever *encoding* you have into whatever you stated for the table/column.  But you must state it correctly.

I *think* you had `big5` data coming in, but you claimed it was `latin1`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem ??

Comment: If everything was back to normal and vanilla (like I was trying to get you to do in my comments above), you should `ALTER` the table back to `big5` charset - **Do NOT `CONVERT`**. Then when your data should be correctly decoded when return to Python.

Comment: I don't get it... Can you say more specific ?

Comment: First, what encoding are you getting as input?  Then we can discuss how to do it safely.  Get a hex dump, _before_ importing, of, say, the coordinate string.